# Selecting element type with attribute value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can someone please let me know the correct way to select an element type with a given attribute?  In my particular case I'm trying to access a label with a an attribute of "for" that has a value of "P500_CB_TRANSFERUNIVERSITY".

I would have though the propery jQuery syntax would be something like
`$('label [for=P500_CB_TRANSFERUNIVERSITY]')` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Show your markup, that jQuery should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the space out and it should work:

```
$("label[for=P500_CB_TRANSFERUNIVERSITY]")
```

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('label[for=P500_CB_TRANSFERUNIVERSITY]')
```

which is exactly the same, just with the space removed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing quotes around the attribute value. This should work fine:

```
$("label[for='P500_CB_TRANSFERUNIVERSITY']")
```

Comment: Quotes aren't needed because there's no spaces.

Comment: The inner quotes aren't the problem.  The issue is the space between label and [.

Comment: ahh didn't even notice the space. I always use quotes, must be out of habit so I thought it was the proper way to do it